# Cross platform movie creation in python

Tags: python, movie

I am developing a small application that generates a stochastic animation, and I would want the option to save the animation as a movie. An obvious solution in linux would be to save the images and `subprocess` a call to `ffmpeg` or the like, but the program should preferable run on windows as well, without any external dependencies and installations needed (I pack the program with pyinstaller for windows). Is there a solution for this, or will I have to depend on different external applications depending on the platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opencv` can solve this cross platform and has python bindings.